# Capitalize the first letter of every word in Scala

Tags: string, scala, capitalization

I know this way

```
val str=org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils.capitalizeFully("is There any other WAY"))
```

Want to know is there any other way to do the Same.

something in Scala Style

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Capitalize the first letter of a string:

```
"is There any other WAY".capitalize
res8: String = Is There any other WAY
```

Capitalize the first letter of every word in a string:

```
"is There any other WAY".split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
res9: String = Is There Any Other WAY
```

Capitalize the first letter of a string, while lower-casing everything else:

```
"is There any other WAY".toLowerCase.capitalize
res7: String = Is there any other way
```

Capitalize the first letter of every word in a string, while lower-casing everything else:

```
"is There any other WAY".toLowerCase.split(' ').map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
res6: String = Is There Any Other Way
```

Answer (score 9):

A bit convoluted, you can use split to get a list of strings and then use capitalize, then mkString to get back the string:

```
scala> "is There any other WAY".split(" ").map(_.capitalize).mkString(" ")
res5: String = Is There Any Other WAY
```

Answer (score 2):

This one will capitalize every word regardless of the separator and doesn't require any additional libraries. It will also handle apostrophe correctly.

```
scala> raw"\b((?<!\b')\w+)".r.replaceAllIn("this is a test, y'all! 'test/test'.", _.group(1).capitalize)
res22: String = This Is A Test, Y'all! 'Test/Test'.
```

Comment: Note to future readers: make sure to `.toLowerCase` before applying this function to your string.

Comment: Not if you want to preserve acronyms or any other custom capitalization, though. In this case do not use .toLowerCase(): 

    `scala> raw"\b((?<!\b')\w+)".r.replaceAllIn("But what about acronyms, such 
as IRS?", _.group(1).capitalize)  
    res1: String = But What About Acronyms, Such As IRS?`

Answer (score -1):

To capitalize the first letter of every word despite of a separator:

```
scala> import com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator
scala> import com.ibm.icu.lang.UCharacter

scala> UCharacter.toTitleCase("is There any-other WAY", BreakIterator.getWordInstance)
res33: String = Is There Any-Other Way
```